# how to define a reference variable in a class that can be either allocated from outside or initialized inside?

Tags: c++, constructor, reference

I intend to write a class that can buffer data in a shared pointer of deque of uint8_t variable

```
shared_ptr<deque<uint8_t>>& received;
```

I need that in future when I instantiate the class without giving argument class use heap memory and also if I pass a variable from outside in constructor for example using static memory it uses it to initialize this buffer so I wrote this

```
struct ICommunication
{

    shared_ptr<deque<uint8_t>>& received;
    ICommunication() 
    {
         received = make_shared<deque<uint8_t>>();

    }
    ICommunication(shared_ptr<deque<uint8_t>>& received)
    {
        this->received = received;
    }
};
```

but cmpiler complain about default constructor that

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error C2530   'ICommunication::received': references must be initialized

how can I solve this?

Comment: why do you want to have a reference to a shared pointer as member?

Comment: btw in your code, both ways wont work, also in the constructor you have to initialize the reference, because references must be initialized. I have the feeling you simply want a shared pointer as member not a reference

Comment: I am programming for an embedded device so I want to be able to initialize it from outside for example allocating a static memory and the send reference and use  that memory and if it is not initialized from outside it automatically use heap memory by allocation memory dynamically

Comment: ok, but why a reference? A pointer is already a level of indirection, why add another one?

Comment: References need to be initialised in the initialiser list of a constructor, not assigned in the body.   Either way, having a reference member of a class that is initialised to something local to the class (e.g. a reference to another member) in some circumstances and to something outside the class in other circumstances is a recipe for trouble  (e.g. if an object outside the class is destroyed, the reference is then dangling, and any use of it gives undefined behaviour).

Comment: Both constructors won't increase the use count of the shared_ptr, and the first one will cause `received` to become invalid after exiting the ctor.

Comment: @idclev463035818 If I am wrong correct me If I don't use reference assignment will copy all variable into my local variable and if deque is big it is not desirable though now that I wrote this I think just shared_ptr overhead variable is being copied

Comment: If it is not possible what can I do instead , Is there any workaround?

Comment: its a (smart) pointer, copying a pointer will not copy the object.

Comment: yeah I think It would be better not using reference for a shared_ptr.

Comment: @peter I want to make it flexible for using allocating static memory from outside so the one who intend to use static memory must be careful to maintain memory appropriately

Comment: @david - I got that.  My point is that such "flexibility" makes it easier for the user of your class to get into trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really don't want or need a reference to a `shared_ptr`.  `ICommunication` should be participating in the lifetime of the pointer and if you get rid of it being a reference, this is exactly what you'll get, and the code will compile:

```
struct ICommunication
{

    shared_ptr<deque<uint8_t>> received;
    ICommunication() : received(make_shared<deque<uint8_t>>()) {}

    ICommunication(shared_ptr<deque<uint8_t>>& received)
    {
        // gives up ownership of the current pointer (may cause the underlying pointer to be deleted)
        // and adds itself to the ownership of the new pointer
        this->received = received;
    }
};
```

Yes, this does copy the `shared_ptr`, **but it does not copy what it points to**, since all copies of a `shared_ptr` point to the same underlying object.